# django-cookiecutter, docker-compose run: can't type in terminal

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, cookiecutter-django

I'm having an issue with a project started with django cookiecutter.

To verify that the issue was not with my project, I'm testing on a blank django cookiecutter project.

The issue is that when I run:

```
docker-compose -f production.yml run --rm django python manage.py createsuperuser
```

I get the prompt but can't type in the terminal.

Same thing when I run:

```
docker-compose -f production.yml run --rm django python manage.py shell
```

I get the shell prompt, but I can't type.

The app is running on a machine on DigitalOcean created with the docker-machine create command.

Any thoughts on what the issue could be and how I could debug this?

Answer (score 0):

to enable typing in docker-compose terminal, you need to specify the terminal session is interactive on the `docker-compose.yml`. Because by default, docker console is not interactive.

```
stdin_open: true
tty: true
```

Comment: -i and -t are not options for docker-compose

Comment: my bad, the configuration then.

Answer (score 0):

`bash` can be accessed inside the docker container using the following command.

```
docker-compose -f production.yml exec django bash
```

This will give you full access to the container of your django server.
There you can run all your normal django commands with full interactivity.

*Create Superuser*

```sh
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

**For Local ENV**

```
docker-compose -f local.yml exec django bash
```